# Правильное ли это решение? Есть ли более оптимальное?

Tags: javascript, for

Есть массив с именами:

```js
const names = ['vLadiMir', 'MaRk', 'LoGAn', 'VicTOr', 'mAks', 'KaTe', 'AlEx'];

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  names[i] = names[i].toLowerCase();
  names[i] = names[i][0] + names[i][1] + names[i][2].toUpperCase() + names[i].slice(3)
  console.log(names[i]);
}
```

Задача: все символы должны быть в нижнем регистре, кроме 3-го, подскажите правильная ли это реализация? Либо можно оптимизировать?

И 2-й вопрос, как быть если нужно сделать upperCase для каждой 3-го символа, т.е для 3-го, 6-го, 9-го и т.д

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я не вижу что на скрине написано.

Comment: Изображение увеличивается по клику

Comment: Код вставляется редактированием

Comment: Вставил)) Думал скриншотом будет удобнее. Там же результат с консоли есть.

Comment: @salco2012, тут можно сниппеты вставлять, тогда полная интеракция будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так еще, но не сказал бы, что это более оптимизировано. Просто выглядит получше.

А ответ на второй вопрос, добавляем переменную `i` - индекс, буква под которым должна быть в аперкейсе.

```js
const i = 2;
const names = ['vLadiMir', 'MaRk', 'LoGAn', 'VicTOr', 'mAks', 'KaTe', 'AlEx']
  .map(e => e.slice(0, i).toLowerCase() + e[i].toUpperCase() + e.slice(i + 1).toLowerCase());

console.log(names);
```

Либо так, если хотим несколько букв:

```js
const i = [2, 4];
const names = ['vLadiMir', 'MaRk', 'LoGAn', 'VicTOr', 'mAks', 'KaTe', 'AlEx']
  .map(e => {
    const out = [...e.toLowerCase()];
    for (const j of i) {
      if (out.length > j) out[j] = out[j].toUpperCase();
    }
    return out.join('');
  });

console.log(names);
```